# AWS CLI $PATH Settings

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am following the [AWS CLI Setup guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-other-os). I have managed to successfully install the tool on my Mac OS X terminal with the following output:

```
Running cmd: /usr/bin/python virtualenv.py --python /usr/bin/python /Users/fr/.local/lib/aws
Running cmd: /Users/fr/.local/lib/aws/bin/pip install --no-index --find-links file:///Users/fr/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.5.3.tar.gz
You can now run: /Users/fr/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws --version
```

My issue is that I have to type the full path **/Users/fr/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws** to execute any **aws** command. As per the guide's final step, I should be able to execute aws command directly without typing the absolute path for it to execute.

When I try using just **aws**, I get the following output:

```
aws --version                                                                                         ⏎
command not found: aws
```

I followed the instructions to make sure that **~/bin** is in my **PATH** environment and I could see there was no output, hence, I executed the export **PATH=~/bin:$PATH** command to add **~/bin to $PATH**. But this has made no difference. The **aws** command does not work directly.

Could someone please advise what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 266):

Here are the three steps to install AWS cli on mac OSX (curl or wget) The third step will set you path correctly

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

The other easiest way is to do using homebrew

```
brew install awscli
```

If you want the development version you can do

```
brew install awscli --HEAD
```

Comment: `brew install awscli` was the way to go for me

Comment: omg.. through like 1 hour of trying to get the cli to work, `brew install awscli` worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you!  Brew failed with a permissions issue `Error: An unexpected error occurred during the 'brew link' step` but curl worked.

Comment: brew install awscli is the most straightforward one

Comment: Please note what documentation states: 
`Package managers such yum, apt-get, or Homebrew for macOS are often behind several versions of the AWS CLI` so be sure to check the version after installing.

Comment: brew the easiest way ))

Answer (score 62):

This worked for me (note: change 2.7 to your specific Python version):

```
export PATH=~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:$PATH
```

You'll likely want to add this to the end of your `.bash_profile` using:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 50):

when you run the command:
`pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user`

watch closely where the aws cli tool gets installed, you can see the path on terminal log, in my case I got something like this:

`awscli in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages`

Now you should add to your .bash_profile the same path but on the bin folder(removing from the lib path and instead put your bin path) like this:

`export PATH=/Users/xuser/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:$PATH`

Comment: your post helped me.

Comment: This made my day

Comment: On python 2.7, it got added to ./Library/Python/2.7/bin

Comment: Best answer for me. No point going around a problem by just using brew. It's so much better to know why it's broken! Thankyou Juan

Answer (score 47):

I have used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install AWS CLI and I am quite happy with the result. Simply type:

```
$ brew install awscli
```

after you have installed brew.

Note, on the [AWS CLI installation page](http://brew.sh/) there is the following disclaimer:

> The awscli package may be available in repositories for other package managers such as APT, yum and Homebrew, but it is not guaranteed to be the latest version.

That said, I have not found this to be a problem, the [awscli.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/awscli.rb) has been updated quite frequently to match the latest releases.

---

Update: there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/727) that suggests that Homebrew should be added as an alternative in the AWS CLI installation instructions. This issue was later closed in favor of this [UserVoice feature request](https://aws.uservoice.com/forums/598381-aws-command-line-interface/suggestions/33168301-install-aws-cli-using-homebrew).

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
PATH=/Users/fr/.local/lib/aws/bin:$PATH
```

(put it in .profile file)

Also try to install aws cli with homebrew. It will add it to your path automatically.

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me as well and did not want to install brew anymore, because everything was running fine already. I also followed the 'tutorial' on AWS site and had problem in the export path step.

Basically, it added a different python folder as the one, where awscli was downloaded. So instead of `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH`
what they suggested I used a full path from disk:
`export PATH=/Users/abc/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:$PATH`

Answer (score 9):

sometimes while classpath's are messed up on mac - you could always run to fix aws cli locally

```
$ brew install awscli
```

which would re-use and update the existing package and set up the right classpath

Answer (score 5):

I've just had the same error and I was able to solve it by adding the following line to my `.bash_profile` file:

**`export PATH=~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:$PATH`**

Please check the version of Python as it may be slightly different on your system. This avoids adding your username folder to the `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Anaconda version of python on your system, please use **conda** to install awscli:

```
conda install -c conda-forge awscli
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm not sure why. My conda environment was deactivated, and I used pip3 as the install command, so I expected conda wouldn't be in the picture at all. Could you explain a little more as to why this works?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure python is installed globally, The steps are like this:

**On AWS side:**

> Go to amazon AWS center -> Services -> Identity and Access Management (IAM) -> Users -> find your User and click on it -> pick Security
> Credentials tab -> create Access Key

**Installation:** On command line / bash

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

**Optional**: if aws version is not found yet ,set up the aws path on your bash profile.

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
#paste this line
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/aws
```

**Configuration:**(Final Step) Configure your credentials as following

```
aws configure
```

Fill in the properties you got from aws website and connect your account. attaching an example for this step.

> AWS Access Key ID [None]: abcd

> AWS Secret Access Key [None]: zyx123!@#

> Default region> name [None]: us-east-1

> Default output format [None]: json

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you AWS CLI has been installed to **/Users/fr/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws**. Hence just create a soft link as below and try, it should work with only **aws** command.

```
$ sudo ln -s /Users/fr/.local/lib/aws/bin/aws /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally had the same issue with aws CodeBuild - I couldn't use the aws cli. I solved it by installing aws globally on my docker image (instead of installing it locally to a user).

```
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade 

(instead of RUN pip install awscli --upgrade --user)
```

It worked for me, if that can help anyone !

Answer (score 1):

export PATH=~/Library/Python/3/bin/:$PATH

try it and add this to the end of your bash

hopefully it worked.

Comment: This answer has conversational sentences and lacks formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the same as Piotr and it's good to understand how to update your path without 3rd party software. However as 3rd party software goes Homebrew is pretty awesome and its a good thing to use it for keeping your dependency symlinks controlled in one place. de facto pkg mgr on mac.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the Virtual Environment method at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-virtualenv.html

without activating the virtualenv:
`source ~/cli-ve/bin/activate` in the documented example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the note on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-bundle.html

> By default, the install script runs under the system default version of Python. If you have installed an alternative version of Python and want to use that to install the AWS CLI, run the install script with that version by absolute path to the Python executable.

For the step where you run the install executable

instead of doing just:

`$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws`

Find out where your python is installed for example

`$ which python`

and then use the path to install the executable like

`$ sudo <path from executing which python> awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws`

The above should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I try usigng CLI

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"

$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip

$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```